# Knockout.js "visible" calling async function - not working

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, knockout.js

I've been trying to understand async, promises, etc. and I think I have a basic understanding of it, but I'm not getting the results I expect.

I have a HTML table, with the following:

```
<table data-bind="visible: viewPrincipal()">
```

viewPrincipal() is a function that should return true or false. This does work at the most basic level if viewPrincipal() just consists of return false or return true.  But what I'm trying to do is call an async function to get the true or false value from there.

```
function viewPrincipal() {
  console.log("Seeing if person is in principal group");
  return IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Principal Members", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
    console.log(isCurrentUserInGroup);
    return isCurrentUserInGroup;
  });
}
```

The console.log works, and returns a true or false as I'd expect it to.  But I want the parent viewPrincipal() function to return that true or false value, and all I get is "undefined".

I understand why this is happening - the IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup() function is taking a bit of time to complete - but I don't know how to fix it. I know how to chain functions together, but when I'm trying to use something like knockout.js to determine if a table should be visible or not, I don't know how to chain.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit lost with your approach, but I'll try to help.

First, please double-think whether you really want to implement access control on the client side. Simply hiding an element if the user does not have sufficient rights is pretty dangerous, since the (possibly) sensitive content is still there in the DOM, it is still downloaded, all you do like this is not displaying it. Even a newbie hacker would find a way to display it though - if nothing else he can simply view it using the F12 tools.

Second, is that triple embedding of functions really necessary? You have an outermost function, that calls a function, which, in turn, calls the provided callback. You could clear this up by using [computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    var serverData = ko.observable(null);
    this.viewPrincipal = ko.computed(function() {
        var srvDataUnwrapped = serverData();    // access the inner value

        if (!srvDataUnwrapped) {
            return false;
        }

        // Do your decision logic here...

        // return false by default
        return false;
    });

    // Load the permission details from the server, this will set
    // a variable that the viewPrincipal depends on, this will allow
    // Knockout to use its dependency tracking magic and listen for changes.
    (function() {
        $.ajax(url, {
            // other config
            success: function (data) {
                serverData(data);
            }
        );
    })();
};

var vm = new viewModel();
```

and then in your view:

```
<table data-bind="visible: viewPrincipal">
```

note the lack if `()`'s here, it is an `observable`, so Knockout will know how to use it.

If this seems overly complicated to add to your already existing code, then you could simply define an `observable` instead, and set the value of that inside your callback:

```
function viewModel() {
    // other stuff ...
    this.viewPrincipal = ko.observable(false);

    // Call this wherever it fits your requirements, perhaps in an init function.
    function checkPrincipal() {
        IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Principal Members", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
            viewPrincipal(isCurrentUserInGroup);
        });
    };
};
```

With this approach, the markup would be the same as in the previous one, that is, without the parentheses:

```
<table data-bind="visible: viewPrincipal">
```

Doing it this way will simply set the inner value of an *observable* inside the callback you pass to `IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup`, and because Knockout is able to track changes of `observable`s, the value change will be reflected in the UI.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! This, along with the other comment here, was very helpful in getting me to understand this whole thing. I realise there's some security holes, but (fortunately for me) the requirement for this change isn't to hide certain data from most people, but instead just make the form smaller and shorter for most people. I'm fine with that for now.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use an observable bool, and let your a-sync function change it's value. Let the magic of two-way-bindings do the rest.

Example:[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/31ycatex/1/)

```
function vm() {
    this.viewPrincipal = ko.observable(false);
};

var vm = new vm();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

function fakeAsync() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        vm.viewPrincipal(true);
    }, 1500);
}
fakeAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me figure out what I should be doing and I now have it working as I'd like.